# Double integral in R with variable in the bound

Tags: r, calculation, integral

How can the below integral be calculated in R? :

[image]

The difficulty is that in the inner integral the upper bound contains one of the variables.

Anyone knows ?

The result must be :
0.0104166666666667

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get this from:

```
integrate(Vectorize(function(y) {
    integrate(function(x) {x*y}, 0, 1-2*y)$value }), 0,0.5)
0.01041667  with absolute error < 1.2e-16
```

Comment: I also found that pracma library is useful for that:`> f <- function(x, y){x*y}
> xmin <- 0; xmax <- 1/2
> ymin <- 0; ymax <- function(y){1 -2*y}
> I <- pracma::integral2(f, xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
> I
$Q
[1] 0.01041667`